# Is the phrase "sent out to be" correct?

Tags: phrases

Is the phrase ***sent*** out to be or ***set*** out to be?

For example:

> He became who he **sent out to be**.

Comment: No, you heard "***set** out to be*". You can look up the phrasal verb [*set out*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=set+out&ls=a&loc=home_ac_Set+out) in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *set out* to be, meaning "started out by intending to become." Merriam-Webster defines *set out* as:

```
 to begin with a definite purpose :  intend, undertake
```